# Jboss 5.1 GA won't start

Tags: jboss

I downloaded Jboss 5.1 GA Windows version, set JBOSS_HOME and tried to run the default coniguration without making any changes. The process seems to fail, even though the last line in the console log says that it's started. I see errors in the log and >http://127.0.0.1:8080< won't load. Am I missing something? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Excerpt from the console log:

```
incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:
  Deployment "CachedConnectionManager" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "TransactionManager" (should be in state "Configured", but is act
ually in state "**ERROR**")
  Deployment "DefaultUserTransactionprovider" is missing the following dependenc
ies:
    Dependency "<UNKNOWN DefaultUserTransactionprovider>" (should be in state "D
escribed", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'TransactionManager'
**")
  Deployment "JBossTimerServiceFactory" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService" (should be in state "Create",
 but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "RealTransactionManager" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "TransactionManager" (should be in state "Instantiated", but is a
ctually in state "**ERROR**")
  Deployment "UnifiedInvoker" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "TransactionManager" (should be in state "Create", but is actuall
y in state "**ERROR**")
  Deployment "WebServer" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.jca:service=CachedConnectionManager" (should be in state "
Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.jca:service=Ca
chedConnectionManager' **")
    Dependency "jboss:service=TransactionManager" (should be in state "Create",
but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss:service=TransactionMana
ger' **")
  Deployment "WorkManager" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "TransactionManager" (should be in state "Configured", but is act
ually in state "**ERROR**")
  Deployment "jboss.admin:service=PluginManager" is missing the following depend
encies:
    Dependency "jboss.jmx:name=Invoker,protocol=jrmp,service=proxyFactory,type=a
daptor" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.ejb:persistencePolicy=database,service=EJBTimerService" is m
issing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.jca:name=DefaultDS,service=DataSourceBinding" (should be i
n state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService" is missing the following depend
encies:
    Dependency "jboss:service=TransactionManager" (should be in state "Create",
but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss:service=TransactionMana
ger' **")
    Dependency "jboss.ejb:persistencePolicy=database,service=EJBTimerService" (s
hould be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.jca:name='jboss-local-jdbc.rar',service=RARDeployment" is mi
ssing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss:service=TransactionManager" (should be in state "Configure
d", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss:service=Transaction
Manager' **")
    Dependency "jboss.jca:service=WorkManager" (should be in state "Configured",
 but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.jca:service=WorkManage
r' **")
  Deployment "jboss.jca:name='jboss-xa-jdbc.rar',service=RARDeployment" is missi
ng the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss:service=TransactionManager" (should be in state "Configure
d", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss:service=Transaction
Manager' **")
    Dependency "jboss.jca:service=WorkManager" (should be in state "Configured",
 but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.jca:service=WorkManage
r' **")
  Deployment "jboss.jca:name='jms-ra.rar',service=RARDeployment" is missing the
following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.jca:service=WorkManager" (should be in state "Configured",
 but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.jca:service=WorkManage
r' **")
    Dependency "jboss:service=TransactionManager" (should be in state "Configure
d", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss:service=Transaction
Manager' **")
  Deployment "jboss.jca:name='mail-ra.rar',service=RARDeployment" is missing the
 following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss:service=TransactionManager" (should be in state "Configure
d", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss:service=Transaction
Manager' **")
    Dependency "jboss.jca:service=WorkManager" (should be in state "Configured",
 but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.jca:service=WorkManage
r' **")
  Deployment "jboss.jca:name='quartz-ra.rar',service=RARDeployment" is missing t
he following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss:service=TransactionManager" (should be in state "Configure
d", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss:service=Transaction
Manager' **")
    Dependency "jboss.jca:service=WorkManager" (should be in state "Configured",
 but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.jca:service=WorkManage
r' **")
  Deployment "jboss.jca:name=DefaultDS,service=DataSourceBinding" is missing the
 following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.jca:name=DefaultDS,service=LocalTxCM" (should be in state
"Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.jca:name=DefaultDS,service=LocalTxCM" is missing the followi
ng dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.jca:service=CachedConnectionManager" (should be in state "
Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.jca:service=Ca
chedConnectionManager' **")
    Dependency "jboss.jca:name=DefaultDS,service=ManagedConnectionPool" (should
be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
    Dependency "jboss:service=TransactionManager" (should be in state "Create",
but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss:service=TransactionMana
ger' **")
  Deployment "jboss.jca:name=DefaultDS,service=ManagedConnectionFactory" is miss
ing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.jca:name='jboss-local-jdbc.rar',service=RARDeployment" (sh
ould be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Instantiated")
  Deployment "jboss.jca:name=DefaultDS,service=ManagedConnectionPool" is missing
 the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.jca:name=DefaultDS,service=ManagedConnectionFactory" (shou
ld be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.jca:name=JmsXA,service=ConnectionFactoryBinding" is missing
the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.jca:name=JmsXA,service=TxCM" (should be in state "Create",
 but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.jca:name=JmsXA,service=ManagedConnectionFactory" is missing
the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.jca:name='jms-ra.rar',service=RARDeployment" (should be in
 state "Create", but is actually in state "Instantiated")
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer" (should be in state "Create"
, but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.jca:name=JmsXA,service=ManagedConnectionPool" is missing the
 following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.jca:name=JmsXA,service=ManagedConnectionFactory" (should b
e in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.jca:name=JmsXA,service=TxCM" is missing the following depend
encies:
    Dependency "jboss.jca:service=CachedConnectionManager" (should be in state "
Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.jca:service=Ca
chedConnectionManager' **")
    Dependency "jboss:service=TransactionManager" (should be in state "Create",
but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss:service=TransactionMana
ger' **")
    Dependency "jboss.jca:name=JmsXA,service=ManagedConnectionPool" (should be i
n state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.jmx:name=Invoker,protocol=jrmp,service=proxyFactory,type=ada
ptor" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss:service=invoker,type=jrmp" (should be in state "Create", b
ut is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.jmx:name=MBeanProxyRemote,protocol=jrmp,type=adaptor" is mis
sing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.jmx:name=Invoker,protocol=jrmp,service=proxyFactory,type=a
daptor" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.messaging.connectionfactory:service=ClusterPullConnectionFac
tory" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice" (should be in state "Create"
, but is actually in state "Configured")
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer" (should be in state "Create"
, but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.messaging.connectionfactory:service=ClusteredConnectionFacto
ry" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice" (should be in state "Create"
, but is actually in state "Configured")
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer" (should be in state "Create"
, but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.messaging.connectionfactory:service=ConnectionFactory" is mi
ssing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice" (should be in state "Create"
, but is actually in state "Configured")
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer" (should be in state "Create"
, but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.messaging.destination:name=DLQ,service=Queue" is missing the
 following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice" (should be in state "Create"
, but is actually in state "Configured")
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer" (should be in state "Create"
, but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.messaging.destination:name=ExpiryQueue,service=Queue" is mis
sing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice" (should be in state "Create"
, but is actually in state "Configured")
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer" (should be in state "Create"
, but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.messaging:service=JMSUserManager" is missing the following d
ependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.jca:name=DefaultDS,service=DataSourceBinding" (should be i
n state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
    Dependency "jboss:service=TransactionManager" (should be in state "Create",
but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss:service=TransactionMana
ger' **")
  Deployment "jboss.messaging:service=PersistenceManager" is missing the followi
ng dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss:service=TransactionManager" (should be in state "Create",
but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss:service=TransactionMana
ger' **")
    Dependency "jboss.jca:name=DefaultDS,service=DataSourceBinding" (should be i
n state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.messaging:service=PostOffice" is missing the following depen
dencies:
    Dependency "jboss:service=TransactionManager" (should be in state "Create",
but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss:service=TransactionMana
ger' **")
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer" (should be in state "Create"
, but is actually in state "Configured")
    Dependency "jboss.jca:name=DefaultDS,service=DataSourceBinding" (should be i
n state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer" is missing the following depen
dencies:
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=JMSUserManager" (should be in state "Cre
ate", but is actually in state "Configured")
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=PersistenceManager" (should be in state
"Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.mq:service=DestinationManager" is missing the following depe
ndencies:
    Dependency "jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer" (should be in state "Create"
, but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/ROOT" is missing the following dependenc
ies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but i
s actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/admin-console" is missing the following
dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but i
s actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/invoker" is missing the following depend
encies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but i
s actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/jbossws" is missing the following depend
encies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but i
s actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/jmx-console" is missing the following de
pendencies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but i
s actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/web-console" is missing the following de
pendencies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but i
s actually in state "Configured")
    Dependency "jboss.admin:service=PluginManager" (should be in state "Create",
 but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss:service=ClientUserTransaction" is missing the following depe
ndencies:
    Dependency "jboss:service=proxyFactory,target=ClientUserTransaction" (should
 be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
    Dependency "jboss:service=proxyFactory,target=ClientUserTransactionFactory"
(should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss:service=KeyGeneratorFactory,type=HiLo" is missing the follow
ing dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.jca:name=DefaultDS,service=DataSourceBinding" (should be i
n state "Create", but is actually in state "Configured")
    Dependency "jboss:service=TransactionManager" (should be in state "Create",
but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss:service=TransactionMana
ger' **")
  Deployment "jboss:service=invoker,type=jrmp" is missing the following dependen
cies:
    Dependency "jboss:service=TransactionManager" (should be in state "Create",
but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss:service=TransactionMana
ger' **")
  Deployment "jboss:service=invoker,type=local" is missing the following depende
ncies:
    Dependency "jboss:service=TransactionManager" (should be in state "Create",
but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss:service=TransactionMana
ger' **")
  Deployment "jboss:service=invoker,type=pooled" is missing the following depend
encies:
    Dependency "jboss:service=TransactionManager" (should be in state "Create",
but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss:service=TransactionMana
ger' **")
  Deployment "jboss:service=proxyFactory,target=ClientUserTransaction" is missin
g the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss:service=invoker,type=unified" (should be in state "Create"
, but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "jboss:service=proxyFactory,target=ClientUserTransactionFactory" is
 missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss:service=invoker,type=unified" (should be in state "Create"
, but is actually in state "Configured")
  Deployment "vfsfile:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/profileservice-se
cured.jar/" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "interface javax.transaction.TransactionManager" (should be in st
ate "Real", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'interface javax.t
ransaction.TransactionManager' **")
    Dependency "interface javax.transaction.TransactionManager" (should be in st
ate "Real", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'interface javax.t
ransaction.TransactionManager' **")
    Dependency "interface javax.transaction.TransactionManager" (should be in st
ate "Real", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'interface javax.t
ransaction.TransactionManager' **")

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "interface javax.transaction.TransactionManager" is in error due to
 the following reason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'interface javax.transaction.T
ransactionManager' **
  Deployment "TransactionManager" is in error due to the following reason(s): co
m.arjuna.ats.arjuna.exceptions.FatalError: [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.Trans
actionStatusManager_9] - Could not get unique port., **ERROR**
  Deployment "jboss.jca:service=WorkManager" is in error due to the following re
ason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.jca:service=WorkManager' **
  Deployment "jboss:service=invoker,type=unified" is in error due to the followi
ng reason(s): Configured
  Deployment "<UNKNOWN DefaultUserTransactionprovider>" is in error due to the f
ollowing reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'TransactionManager' **
  Deployment "jboss:service=TransactionManager" is in error due to the following
 reason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss:service=TransactionManager' **
  Deployment "jboss.jca:service=CachedConnectionManager" is in error due to the
following reason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.jca:service=CachedConnection
Manager' **
  Deployment "jboss.web:service=WebServer" is in error due to the following reas
on(s): Configured

08:01:11,485 INFO  [ServerImpl] JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=
JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221053)] Started in 24s:732ms
```

Comment: Is this the first errors in the console output?

Comment: It's not. See my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set a JAVA_HOME variable, and what JDK are you using?  The recommended JDK for JBoss 5.1 is at least JDK 5.

Comment: Yes, my JAVA_HOME is set. I'm using jdk 1.6u24

Answer (score 0):

Previous error says there is a process listening on one of the attempted ports. That was it. Killed the process and jboss works like a charm now.

Btw. the process turned out to be pulseaudio.exe. No idea what it is and what it was doing with the port 4713...

```
08:53:35,435 WARN  [arjLoggerI18N] [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.TransactionSt
atusManager_14] - Failed to create server socket on address 127.0.0.1 and port:
4,713
08:53:35,435 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Create: name=T
ransactionManager state=Configured
com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.exceptions.FatalError: [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.Tra
nsactionStatusManager_9] - Could not get unique port.
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.TransactionStatusManager.start(Transac
tionStatusManager.java:186)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.TransactionStatusManager.<init>(Transa
ctionStatusManager.java:71)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TxControl.createTransactionStatusMa
nager(TxControl.java:286)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TxControl.<clinit>(TxControl.java:5
18)
        at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService.create(Transact
ionManagerService.java:185)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Comment: You didn't include the relevant exception in your original question.  Virtually impossible to troubleshoot otherwise, hence my comment on your question if this was the first exception.

Comment: You don't add 'answers' to update information on your question, you edit your question... You are still using stackoverflow incorrectly.